# Calling a function in Assembler (AT&T, IA-32)

Tags: function, assembly, x86, call

I just started learning Assembler, and I'm stuck at the very beginning - I'm trying to call a simple function - in fact it's mostly copied from a book, and I keep getting segmentation fault. Maybe someone more experienced could point out what's wrong with this code:

```
.code32
SYSEXIT = 1
.data
.text
.globl _start
_start:
        push $28  #just some random argument
        push $33 
        call myfunc
        mov $SYSEXIT, %eax
        #exit code is stored in ebx after calling  function
        int $0x80
.type myfunc, @function
myfunc:
        push %ebp #save old base pointer on a stack
        movl %esp, %ebp
        movl 8(%ebp), %ebx #first argument to ebx
        movl 12(%ebp), %ecx #second argument to ecx
        addl %ecx, %ebx  #add arguments together - store them in ebx
        movl %ebp, %esp
        pop %ebp
        ret
```

Comment: You probably want `pushl` for your immediate arguments. Otherwise the assembler probably generates an instruction to push a word (16 bits).

Comment: already tried `pushl` and other variations - still getting seg fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function expects the arguments to be longs (32-bit), so you should push them with `pushl` rather than `push`.

You should also make sure that you balance the stack after the function returns. I.e. something like:

```
pushl $28
pushl $33
call myfunc
addl $8,%esp  # "removes" two 32-bit arguments off the stack
```

Comment: Indeed I forgot about balancing the stack. I've tried `pushl` earlier - without any effect. Making your corrections still gives me segmentation fault, unfortunately.

Comment: I've tried to check where the problem is - commenting these lines:

    `movl 8(%ebp), %ebx #first argument to ebx`
    `movl 12(%ebp), %ecx #second argument to ecx`
    `addl %ecx, %ebx  #add arguments together - store them in ebx`
    `movl %ebp, %esp`

Gives me no more segmentation fault

Comment: I've verified that the code works correctly on my machine with the changes I listed in my answer.

Comment: thank you, then If the code is ok I'll try to check if something is wrong with my machine/OS/compiler.

Comment: Try disassembling the binary with `objdump -d` and see if you can spot something that looks fishy. If that doesn't help, run your program in a debugger to see which instruction causes the segfault and what the register values are at that point (if you don't already have a stack trace).

Comment: I've managed to get another computer with the same architecture and it indeed works. I've checked both versions with `objdump -d`, and it seems that "not working" version is compiled to 64-bit (it says `file format elf64-x86-64`, and uses instructions such as `pushq`), even though I made `.code32` directive at the beginning. The working one gets: `file format elf32-i386`.

Comment: Add an `-m32` option when you compile. That's what I did (I'm also on a 64-bit system ATM).

Comment: It says "unrecognized option" (it's "as" compiler on linux), but it has probably just a different name in my compiler - it should be easy from now on. Thank you once again for your help.